# How to increase swap size when there is already a partition existing

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, swap

`~$ sudo swapon --show` gives me this

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda5 partition 976M   0B   -2
```

I want to increase my swap size. Is there a way to increase this or do I have to create a new partition or a file? I have `gparted` installed and I see that there are only 2 partitions as `lsblk` shows below -

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda5   8:5    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0 237.5G  0 part /
```

How do I go about increasing the size?

Comment: Just an observation, not a answer, but if you're actually using that much swap space then your performance is going to be terrible. I'd strongly suggest increasing the amount of physical memory in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-partition you can use a swap *file*. It works like it does on Windows.  Instead of specifying a partition name in your fstab, you specify a file, say, in your root partition.

You will need to initialise the file simply by creating a file containing zeros of your desired size, and make it readable only by root.  Also (I can't remember if this is necessary) format it with:

sudo mkswap /myswapfile

Here are some full instructions:

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/create-a-linux-swap-file/

(It's strange they chose to put it in /mnt, that's not what /mnt is)

You can use the swap file in addition to your existing swap partition, and there should not be a performance hit.  You can even specify a priority in your fstab for what order they should be used, which is for when some of your swap is on a faster device, but that's not really relevant here.